# Markdown Math does not display correctly when deploying Pelican website to Heroku

Tags: python, math, heroku, markdown, pelican

**Problem**: I've downloaded the ['render_math'](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/render_math) plugin for my pelican website to create math formulas in markdown. They display correctly when running locally using pelican --listen, but when I deploy the site to Heroku, the formulas do not display correctly, as shown in the picture below:
[image]

My markdown for the formula:

```
## $$l_t=\beta_0+\beta_1l_{t-1} + \phi_1\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$
```

How it should look when viewed:

[image]

**Attempted solution**: I've included the following plugins path and the plugin used in my pelican config file, but to no effect and no errors are given. It should create a 'span' element in the HTML containing the Math, but it seems to only generate an 'H2' element.

```
PLUGIN_PATHS = ["/content/plugins"]
PLUGINS = ["render_math"]
```

How can I make my math formulas display correctly using markdown when deploying the site to heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lay instead in how MathJax was added to the site and was causing mixed content errors. I switched the CDN link from HTTP to HTTPS, which solved my issue.